# I set a variable to global but when I use it outside the function it does not work

Tags: python, function, variables, global, nameerror

I am trying to make a command system in python.I was expecting that when I enter r/ it would print the given parameter but instead it said:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
    if r in command:
NameError: name 'command' not defined
```

Here is the code that has to do with this:

```
def prompt():
  usrinput = input(">>")
  global command
  command = usrinput.split(' ')

r = "r/"

if r in command:
```

Comment: The link to my code:
https://replit.com/@skelesquidstd/command-line#main.py

Comment: If you've never called your function, it hasn't been run yet. Merely defining it doesn't set the variables up.

Comment: Better if `prompt` returns a value, i.e., `return usrinput.split(' ')`. Then `command = prompt()`. Stop using `global`.

Comment: @BenY I already did that in the code, I just did not show that part. But thank you for the help

Comment: Unless you didn't include it in the question, it's difficult to answer you properly with the portion of code you provided. Just speaking from experience, when I make use of global variables, I tend to initialize it early on (typically with a sentinel value like `None`) in the code just so I can avoid the undefined symbol error. If it's still `None`, it means it was never touched.

Comment: @BenY Oh, Thanks